# Mount camera to pod get MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "default-token-c8hm5" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, nvidia-jetson, mounted-volumes

On my Jetson NX, I like to set a yaml file that can mount 2 cameras to pod,
the yaml:

```
containers:
  - name: my-pod
    image: my_image:v1.0.0

    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /dev/video0
        name: dev-video0
      - mountPath: /dev/video1
        name: dev-video1
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9000
    command: [ "/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10;done"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /dev/video0
        type: ""
      name: dev-video0
    - hostPath:
        path: /dev/video1
        type: ""
      name: dev-video1
```

but when I deploy it as pod, get the error:

```
 MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "default-token-c8hm5" : failed to sync secret cache: timed out waiting for the condition
```

I had tried to remove volumes in yaml, and the pod can be successfully deployed. Any comments on this issue?

Another issue is that when there is a pod got some issues, it will consume the rest of my storage of my Jetson NX, I guess maybe k8s will make lots of temporary files or logs...? when something wrong happening, any solution to this issue, otherwise all od my pods will be evicted...

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?